# I got problem doing Selection Sort in Swift

Tags: swift, algorithm, sorting

I am trying to create a simple Selection Sort in `Swift`. 
I made it without any problems in `C`, but I am suffering this time. Does anyone know what's wrong with my code?

```
var arrayOne: [Int] = [5, 12, 69, 33, 14, 15, 22, 88, 3, 4]

var temp = 0, index = 0
var i = 0, j = 0
var min = 9999

while i < 10 {

    j = i
    while j < 10 {

        if (min > arrayOne[Int(j)]){

            min = arrayOne[Int(j)]
            index = j
        }

        j += 1

    }

    temp = arrayOne[Int(i)]
    arrayOne[Int(i)] = arrayOne[index]
    arrayOne[index] = temp

    i += 1
}

for n in arrayOne {
    print(n)
}
```

**Result**

```
3
5
12
69
33
14
15
22
4
88
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset `min` each time through the outer `while` loop so that you pick up the next `min` value:

```
while i < 10 {
    min = .max  // add this
```

**Notes:**

- `.max` is shorthand for `Int.max`.  Swift infers the type from the fact
  that `max` is declared as `Int`.
- You could move the declaration of `min` into the loop with `var min = Int.max` since `min` is not needed after the loop.  In that case, the `Int` is needed to establish the type.  It could also be written as `var min: Int = .max`.
- `Int.max` is a better choice than `9999` because it works correctly with larger numbers (such as `10000`) and it communicates the intent of the algorithm better.